# grub efi luks encryption, how avoid "decrypt master key"

Tags: grub2, uefi, password, encryption, luks

because I accidentally deleted the luks key slot saved in the keyfile the system (lubuntu 22.04, grub efi) started as normal with password to decrypt master key, which takes very long because of grub being slow. But then the luks partition can't be found and grub hangs.

If I delete the keyfile, the system asks for the password twice, once for decryption of master key then for the luks partition.

If I set GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK=n' in the file '/etc/default/grub' and run update-grub and grub install the system boots without asking the "decrypt master key" password. But now again the luks partition is not found and the system hangs again. I would like to just have to type the password once for the luks partition.

Any ideas how this could be done?
Thanks in advance.